# Missing While loop logic

Tags: java

found this code on the internet, it's missing the while loop logic "while(i....)" for some reason and though I found other working solutions for the PigLatin* problem, I really want to understand how this one is working.

*PigLatin problem: take a sentence, take the first letter from each word and place it at the end of the same word, then suffix "ay". So "I am confused" becomes "Iay maay onfusedcay".

Here is the code:

```
        import java.util.*;
        public class PigLatin {
            
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                        
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                    
                System.out.println("Please enter an English sentence: ");
                String sentence = input.nextLine();
                
                System.out.println("Original sentence: "+sentence);
                System.out.println("PigLatin conversion: "+convert(sentence));
            }
            
        private static String convert (String sentence) {
                
                String []words = sentence.split(" ");
                int i = 0;
                String pigLatin = "";
                while(i ){ //MISSING CODE
                    pigLatin+=words[i].substring(1,words[i].length())+words[i].charAt(0)+"ay"+" ";
                    i++;
                }
                return pigLatin;
            }
        }
```

Thank you.

PS: I basically found the "convert" method on the internet and wrote the rest of the code, tried a few things but could not get the while loop to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop appears to be iterating the `words` array. So it should just be something like

```
while(i < words.length) {
    pigLatin += words[i].substring(1, words[i].length())
            + words[i].charAt(0) + "ay ";
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir Elliott. I did something really dumb, I did try the words.length logic and it did not accept it so I thought that wasn't it, but pasting your code worked and upon cross checking I realized I had the uppercase W for "while". I am a dumbass. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PigLatin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter an English sentence: ");
        String sentence = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Original sentence: "+sentence);
        System.out.println("PigLatin conversion: "+convert(sentence));
    }

    private static String convert (String sentence) {

        String []words = sentence.split(" ");
        int i = 0;
        String pigLatin = "";
        while(i<words.length){ //CORRECTION CODE
            pigLatin+=words[i].substring(1,words[i].length())+words[i].charAt(0)+"ay"+" ";
            i++;
        }
        return pigLatin;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Geek, already got the answer from Elliott. Appreciate your input. :)

Comment: @user7642744 No need of -1 then. Anyways

Comment: That wasn't me, not sure why someone voted it down. My guess is probably because the exact same answer was posted above and accepted. I upvoted it. Cheers.